# What is the easiest way to make this vertical menu?

Tags: jquery, navigation

I need to make a dynamic menu that looks exactly like this. I figure JQuery is easiest to use for it (accordion?). If someone could link me to a specific implementation I'd appreciate it.
[image]     [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

The jQuery UI Accordion widget is easy to implement. Basically, you just set up a `<ul>` element and call the `accordion()` method on it. The rest is just styling.

If you have trouble, post another, more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) is fantastic for that, another possibility that might be more suitable is [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check these links .Create  accordion menu like this and count number of sub menus using php. 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/09/create-accordion-menu-jquery.html

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu-glossy.htm

You need to iteate a loop to count `<li>` tags inside that particular `<ul>` tag.